# Address in format for the given country

Tags: c#, .net

is there some implementation of "Address" class which can be filled with address data and it would return it in the outline for the given country. It would implement something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195167.aspx).

It would be used like:

```
AddressFormater af = new AddressFormater();
af.Street1 = "Street part";
af.Postal = 91000;
af.City = "London";
//other address data
af.GetAddress(new CultureInfo("en"));
```

Or something in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BING's API to "Find a Location by Address"
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx)
and specify a "Supported Culture Codes" parameter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441729.aspx) which will bring back what you want.